# filter_var behaves differently on different servers

Tags: php, filtering

I think filter_var works differently on my different servers, here is the code I'm running:

```
$url = "http://www.my-domain.com";
$urlOriginal  = "http://www.my-domain.com";
$url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED | FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED);
echo $url;
echo "<br/>Php version: " .  phpversion();


echo "<br/><h1>";
if ($url == $urlOriginal){
    echo "it worked because $url == $urlOriginal";
} else {
    echo "it didn't work, because $url != $urlOriginal";
}
echo "</h1>";
```

The output on one server is

```
http://www.my-domain.com
Php version: 5.2.13
it worked because http://www.my-domain.com == http://www.my-domain.com
```

On the other it is

```
Php version: 5.2.13
it didn't work, because != http://www.my-domain.com
```

Since they are both using the same version of PHP I think this is probably related somehow to how things are configured, any idea what that is?

I also found this which may be relevant:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51305&edit=1

Comment: notice $url is missing in example 2. what does var_dump($url) return?

Comment: @Dagon because `filter_var` returns `false` in case of *malformed* input, which is empty string, when converted into string. @user893730 Are you sure, constants like `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` are not redefined? Do both server have the same OS?

Comment: that's why i asked for the result of var_dump :_)

Comment: @Dagon The output of vardump for the first one is string 'http://www.my-domain.com' (length=24) for second one is boolean false

Comment: @kirilloid , the Operating Systems are not the same, the first one is Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l  2.6.32-5-amd64 the second one is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago) Linux www1.n49.ca 3.2.12-3.2.4.amzn1.x86_64, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL  is not redefined in this code

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the output of this code on your machines if you've tried it does it work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug<sup>1</sup> in PHP 5.2.13 for domains containing hyphens. The same bug was present PHP 5.3.2 since they were both broken/fixed at the same time.  PHP 5.2.14 and 5.3.3 onwards will work just fine, as will 5.2.12/5.3.1 and below, with regards to this particular bug.

As for why one server works and the other doesn't, different operating systems offer different PHP installations with various patches applied (or not) making them often different to installing PHP from source.  The server where the code worked has a patch applied in their version of PHP 5.2.13, whereas the other server does not.

<sup>1</sup> https://bugs.php.net/51192